# How to build a real live post system on my page using PHP and MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am building a PHP website. The main purpose of the website site is as follows:

1. PHP to check database and see if a user's birthdate (day and month) is equal to today's date (day and month) and if its equal, PHP should echo example "Today is James Oduro's Birthday". This will be echoed on the main page "go.php"
2. PHP should check database and show all registered members on the main page "go.php" which includes user's FirstName, LastName and Birthdates and Picture.
3. User should be able to post a simple congratulation message on the page to other users who are having their Birthdays.

Now, I have done 50% percent of the work which includes "PHP login script and validation", registration script, and validation using PHP, PHP checking database and seeing if a user has birthday and echoing on the main page  and Also showing all registered members on the page, logout script and PHP echoing user's Firstname on top of the page using SESSIONS variables.

My website is on a testing server and I would want to give you an account to login see how the page looks like and I would ask questions regarding to it.

```
account to login is : Email: jamesoduro@yahoo.com, Password: test, Address is: www.bsystem.besaba.com
```

I assume you've login already so my question follows:

1. How should I implement PHP code that when user's write something and click on post then it will be stored in database and later show it on the page under the post form?
2. How can I also let users upload their simple avator or photo and show it behind their name and details on the Registered members?

Please note that I will provide all my codes and files upon request.

Comment: Hi James. As interesting as your project is, questions here are better if they are potentially relevant to a future audience; however, this one is highly localised, because the code is not shown and you've asked for people to log on to a server. I assume that once you fix the problem the credentials will no longer work, so future readers will not be able to see the problem. If you can trim this question down to a _specific_ problem, that would be ideal.

Comment: Don't worry I can post the whole code ...I tried doing that but the JS character count wont let me post the whole code here... as am limited to posting too many lines of codes @halfer

Comment: That's a good start, but it sounds like the question scope needs focussing as well - you'll then find that you'll not need to post the whole project. I wonder if getting some practice with good quality PHP tutorials might help?

Comment: yes. it might really help. Do you have tutorials?@halfer

Comment: I do have one, as it happens - see my profile for the link. It's quite a substantial tutorial - nearly book length - so don't try to complete it in a single day!

Comment: which particular link in regards of my project.?@halfer

Comment: There's only one tutorial there - it's called "I ♥ PHP".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok first create a table in database and name it user_post like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_post` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_post` text NOT NULL,
  `post_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `post_status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `user_post`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

 ALTER TABLE `user_post`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

using your post form insert post on submit button click like below

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into `user_post`(`user_id`,`user_post`,`post_time`,`post_status`) values('".$_SESSION['user_id']."','".$_POST['post']."',now(),1)");
```

Fetch code like below

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from `user_post` where user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' order by id DESC");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{?>
    Your Html Code
<?php }?>
```

remember session value i have taken is just an example you have to take your session value in place of mine

hope this will help you..

Comment: .I tried your answer and I converted to MySQLi...it is working fine but I still have a problem again...the problem is 1. the post form name is "globalstatus"   so I set the form Action to "post.php" Now when I click on post buttom(submit) , the main page is redirected to "post.php" how do i fix that.    2. I want the FirstName of the  person who posted to be also echoed ..How to fix that. I needed to tell you that I have two tables in my database. is it because I didn't put all in one table? the code provided below:

Comment: //setting connection variables
$hostname = "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password ="";
$db= "cemembers";
$_SESSION['Email'] = "FirstName"; $_SESSION['FirstName'] = 1; 
$globalstatus = $_POST['globalstatus'];
//connect to database
$mysqli_db = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password, $db);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}
if(!empty($globalstatus)){
 $sql="INSERT INTO `user_post`(`user_id`,`user_post`,`post_time`,`post_status`) values('".$_SESSION['Email']."','".$_POST['globalstatus']."',now(),1)";

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db,$sql);

 }
?>

Comment: 2.if you want to show FirstName of the person who posted so you can take firstname in session along with username or user id or whatever you have taken..

Comment: alright will try the answer 2.  1st problem is: on my HTML page of the main page g.php, I have the I have form1. here the the HTML code:<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="post.php">

<textarea name="globalstatus" maxlength="130" autofocus wrap="hard" id="globalstatus" form="form1" placeholder="Say Somthing..." title="Say a congratulation message to someone." onKeyDown="limit(this,130);" onKeyUp="limit(this,130);"></textarea. AS YOU CAN SEE, the form1 action is post.php where the form is control . MY PROBLEM IS WHEN I CLICK ON POST button it INSERT VALUE TO DATABASE ALRIGHT.

Comment: but the main paga "go.php" is redirected to the php script that controls the post form1. I am asking how do I make the main page "go.php" stand or remain whenever a user click on post buttom and yet still have value inserted into database alright . I don't want to click on back on the browser before I see the new post shown. @vivek

Comment: I want something like if after INSERT INTO database header("location:go.php") echo your post has been successful. on the same page. @Vivek

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply insert post into database table using the user's session value like username or whatever you want to store with the post and time of post with a status(active/deactive).. and after every insertion you can fetch all the records from table using session's value that you stored in table..
you can fetch using php or can use ajax for showing post on runtime

Comment: ok that's seems a lot of php coding.I am 6months php programmer and I know little...please can you provide me with some coding and upon that I will learn  on that? @vivek

Answer (score 0):

You can get person which is birthday today, using following query. 
but Instead of static date you need to Date('d') it will give current day and Date('m') it will give current month, its a php functions

SELECT * FROM `tbl_birth` WHERE DAY(birdthData)=DAY('2015-03-21') AND MONTH(birdthData)=MONTH('2015-03-21')

Comment: I think with the php echoing person birthdays is already done. I used the following code. $weekday=date("l");
$y = date("Y");
$day = date("d");
 $m =date("M");
 $currentdate = $weekday." ". $m ." ".$day." ".$y;
 
 echo "<div id='cdate'>"."Today is"." " .$currentdate ."</div>"."<br>"."<span class='welcometxt'>"."<h1 class='current'>"."Current Birthday (s)"."</h1>"."</span>"; @Nimish Mer

Comment: $checkbd = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Day, Month FROM users";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $checkbd);

 
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
  
  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
   
   
   if($row["Day"] == $day && $row["Month"]==$m){
    
    
    echo "<p class='t1'>"."Today is"." ".$row["FirstName"]." ".$row["LastName"]."'s"." "."Birthday" ."<br>"."</p>";
    
    } @Nimish Mer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to insert on the same html page than leave from action like below

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

and before insertion code check a condition submit button's value is set or not like below

```
if(isset($_POST['your_submit_button_name']))
{
$sql=mysql_query("insert into `user_post`(`user_id`,`user_post`,`post_time`,`post_status`) values('".$_SESSION['user_id']."','".$_POST['post']."',now(),1)");
if($sql)
{?>
<script>
alert("your post has been successfully posted");
window.location.href='your_desired_location.php';
</script>

<?php }}?>
```

Comment: Thank you. your script work for me but I use this instead.. $sql="INSERT INTO `user_post`(`user_id`,`user_post`,`post_time`,`post_status`) values('".$_SESSION['Email']."','".$_POST['globalstatus']."',now(),1)";
 
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db,$sql);
 if($result== true ){
  
  
  header("location:go.php");
  echo  "<div class='postsucces'>"."Your Post was succesful"."</div>"; Thank you I will continue my project tomorrow... thanks for the much help.@vivek

Comment: if it works for you please don't forget to right the answer and upvote so some other user can get help easily using this answer.. thanx